# check keyboard state without using KeyboardEvent in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, keyboard-events, enterframeevent

Is it possible to check for pressed keys without using the KeyboardEvent?

I have an ENTER_FRAME event setup called enterFrameHandler and I want to check within the function enterFrameHandler if any keys are pressed.

normally when using a KeyboardEvent I could check for keys easily using a switch that checks the KeyCode of the event, but in an ENTER_FRAME event this isn't possible for me.

Is there any other way of checking the keyboard's state within the ENTER_FRAME event?

UPDATE:
I found this AS2 script:

```
onClipEvent (enterFrame) {
    if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)) {
        _x -= power;
    }
    if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)) {
        _x += power;
    }
    if (Key.isDown(Key.UP)) {
        _y -=power;
    }
    if (Key.isDown(Key.DOWN)) {
        _y +=power;
    }
}
```

This seems to be doing what I want, but it's in AS2, does anyone know how to 'translate' this into AS3?

Comment: See my answer for a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501424/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-test-for-combined-keyboard-arrow-direction-in-a/2502380#2502380

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store key states in a dictionary or object:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyHandleUp);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyHandleDown);

private var hash:Object = {};

private function keyHandleUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    delete hash[event.keyCode];
}

private function keyHandleDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    hash[event.keyCode] = 1;
}

private function isKeyDown(code:int):Boolean {
    return hash[code] !== undefined;
}
```

Comment: The above code does not compile because event.keycode is missing the capital C.  "keyCode"

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no
Why don't you want to use a KeyboardEvent event listener?

Comment: I could, but I'm curious now I know this is possible with AS2

Comment: @just_a_dude. Being able to check whether a particular key is down at a given time is very convenient. For example, in the main loop of a game, where you check for user input at a centralized point. That is what this class lets you do:  http://code.google.com/p/bigroom/source/browse/trunk/src/uk/co/bigroom/input/KeyPoll.as. It was possible to do it natively in AS 2. Not sure why now you are forced to implement it in Actionscript, but I digress.

Comment: @JuanPabloCalifano you don't need to digress Juan. keep gressing. gress all you want. also, thanks for the link but it is giving a 404. do you have a example of what it was doing?

Answer (score 0):

With a `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN` listener added to the stage, keeping the key pressed works just fine, so there's no need for the ENTER_FRAME.

```
private function keyDownHandler(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch(evt.keyCode)
    {
        case 37: //left key
                trace("Move left");
            break;
        case 38: //up key
            trace("Move up");
            break;
        case 39: //right key
            trace("Move right");
            break;
        case 40: //down key
            trace("Move down");
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Or you could use an EventDispatcher on ENTER_FRAME, but i'm pretty sure it'd run way slower than using the KeyboardEvent.