# How to store keycode value to variable? (flash as3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, keycode

I'm new to AS3. I tried to move a object with keyboard event. I used if/else condition to check that if keycode is this... then statement run.

But I'm not able to do it with switch method. I want to take a variable. what will store the keycode which key I'm pressing. & It will check for statement that I pressed 37 key, so object go to left.

So my problem is that, how to store current keycode (what key is pressing) to variable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613196/check-keyboard-state-without-using-keyboardevent-in-as3/2624924#2624924

Answer (score 3):

```
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, _keyboard);


    private function _keyboard(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
    {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 38: // arrow up
                trace("It Works!");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Any problems with this?

As you can see your event stores information about keycode, and you can access it through it. Also note that listener is added to stage.

Comment: oh. Thanks you so much for kindness. I was too close. But I didn't that I can use e.keycode to in switch. Its works great. Thanks again "Lukasz Zaroda"